# How to store range of date?

Tags: mysql

I am developing an analytics tool that track how many time a user spend to do an action.

So I am using this approach:

**Database table:** id_user ( int ), action ( varchar ), type ( int ), startstop ( datetime )

*type* can be only 0 or 1 and indicate if the action is started or stopped.

---

When the user start the action, then a new row is inserted in the database via ajax request ( for example: 1, action_1, 1, 12:22:54 )

When the user stop the action, then a new row is inserted in the database via ajax request ( for example: 1, action_1, 0, 13:31:11 )

Do you think this is a good approach or are there more simple and efficient ways to do this ?

Comment: Why don't you have one record, with a field `timeStart` and a field `timeStop`?  When the action is stopped, update the record.  This way, you don't double record the action and only have one record_id.  This will cut the number of records in half, and use less memory (not as much as half, though).

Comment: I would certainly consider Sablefoste's suggestion; 6 months/12 months/18th months from now I might be grateful to have a ~580MB database backup instead of a ~1GB one, for example ...

Comment: great, other suggestions :) ?

Answer (score 0):

Re-write your table fields into `id_user ( int )`, `action ( varchar )`, `time_start ( datetime )`, `time_stop ( datetime )` instead.

Update the field `time_stop` with the current time the action was stopped.